# multiple host files in apache

Tags: apache, virtualhost, httpd.conf

I know I can configure multiple virtualhost configurations in multiple file by including them in httpd.conf.

Can apache support this arrangement while any incorrect configuration in one file doesn't affect another or I can say Apache as whole.

Comment: I don't think there is a way for Apache to skip broken config files. But why do you need this in the first place (= why do you expect having broken configuration files on your server)?

Comment: Ah, this is probably related to this question of yours: [Site level Apache configurations in linux](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19960364) The answer is very likely that this is not possible. Just have two servers and be done with it

Comment: Hi Pekka thanks for the speedy reply. Actually we have a server arrangement in which we want different users to have their working shells.
Now we want to give them access to modify there virtualhost configurations as they like and apply them without affecting other site.
I have created a solution for this using shell scripts to validate the changes etc. but it will be good to know if apache support this type arrangement.

Comment: I have the LOAD BALANCER arrangement but still if user give any invalid configuration that node is going down.

Comment: Hmm, I doubt whether it's possible. You could try asking on http://serverfault.com but make sure to add all the info from the comments